# Why only static member can access private destructor?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MonsterDB
{
private:
    ~MonsterDB() {}; //private destructor
public:
    static void DestroyInstance(MonsterDB* pInstance)
    {
        //static member can access private destructor
        delete pInstance;
    }
    //...other methods
};
int main()
{
    // instantiation in heap
    MonsterDB* pMyDatabase = new MonsterDB();

    MonsterDB::DestroyInstance(pMyDatabase);
    
    return 0;
}
```

guys , why only static member can access private destructor?

When i remove static from this :

```
static void DestroyInstance(MonsterDB* pInstance)
```

i get an error!

The reason i asked the question is that :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MonsterDB
{
private:
    int variable;

    
    
public:
    void printer()
    {
        cout<<variable<<endl;
    }
    void instancer(int s)
    {
        variable = s;
    }
    
    //...other methods
};

int main()
{
    MonsterDB obj1;
    int var = 5;
    obj1.instancer(var);
    obj1.printer();
}
```

In the above code I made, both functions : printer and instancer accessed private variable without having to specify static keyword in those functions.

Sorry for your time, advance thanks! hoping to give real intuition behind this.

Comment: `MonsterDB::DestroyInstance` calls a `static` function. If you try to call a non-`static` function this way it will obviously error out

Comment: yup, could you please tell me why static function only be worked there?

Comment: I mean the intuition on why static function can only access private destructors?

Comment: You could use a non-`static` function, but that obviously also requires changing how you call it. That has nothing to do with the destructor being `private`

Comment: You get *what* error?

Comment: Any member function of a class or any `friend` of the class can access a private destructor of your class (or do an operation that causes the destructor to be called).   The problem, in your case, is that `main()` is not a member function of the class, nor is it a `friend` of the class.    Also,non-static member functions need to be called from outside the class in the form `some_object.member()` or `some_pointer_to_object->member()`, not as `MonsterDB::member()`

Comment: yeah got that, thanks!

Comment: Show the code that **doesn't** work, not the code that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might recall, `static` (in this context) means that the function behaves like a global function, meaning it is *not* bound to a single instance of the class.

```
MonsterDB::DestroyInstance(pMyDatabase);
```

Obviously, if `DestroyInstance` is not `static`, this line will always fail (and it has nothing to do with private destructors). Calling it like this

```
pMyDatabase->DestroyInstance(pMyDatabase);
```

will work even if the method is not static (although it is very awkward, it makes more sense to make this method static).

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me! Sorry for your time.